# inflating class AutoCompleteTextView Exception on Kitkat And Below

Tags: android

AutoCompleteTextView crashes on OS kitkat and below , i have attached the xml and the exception logs

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/eight_dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight_dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/eight_dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eight_dp"/>
```

Here is my log :

> exception logs android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class AutoCompleteTextView at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater‌​.java:719) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761‌​) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769‌​) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)

Comment: exception logs
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class AutoCompleteTextView
               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)

Comment: Add full logcat . And where in your java code you are getting exception. Paste the code also where you access this AutoComplete TextView.

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution? I am getting same error